# Longest consecutive count of the same value per group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have a data.frame as below and I want to add a variable describing the longest consecutive count of 1 in the `VALUE` variable observed in the group (i.e. longest consecutive rows with 1 in `VALUE` per group).

```
GROUP_ID    VALUE
    1         0
    1         1
    1         1
    1         1
    1         1
    1         0
    2         1
    2         1
    2         0
    2         1
    2         1
    2         1
    3         1
    3         0
    3         1
    3         0
```

So the output would look like this:

```
GROUP_ID    VALUE    CONSECUTIVE
    1         0           4
    1         1           4
    1         1           4
    1         1           4
    1         1           4
    1         0           4
    2         1           3
    2         1           3
    2         0           3
    2         1           3
    2         1           3
    2         1           3
    3         1           1
    3         0           1
    3         1           1
    3         0           1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(GROUP_ID) %>% 
  mutate(CONSECUTIVE = {rl <- rle(VALUE); max(rl$lengths[rl$values == 1])})
```

which gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 16 x 3
> # Groups:   GROUP_ID [3]
>    GROUP_ID VALUE CONSECUTIVE
>       <int> <int>       <int>
>  1        1     0           4
>  2        1     1           4
>  3        1     1           4
>  4        1     1           4
>  5        1     1           4
>  6        1     0           4
>  7        2     1           3
>  8        2     1           3
>  9        2     0           3
> 10        2     1           3
> 11        2     1           3
> 12        2     1           3
> 13        3     1           1
> 14        3     0           1
> 15        3     1           1
> 16        3     0           1
> ```

---

Or with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)            # convert to a 'data.table'

dat[, CONSECUTIVE := {rl <- rle(VALUE); max(rl$lengths[rl$values == 1])}
    , by = GROUP_ID][]
```

Comment: Alternately, use `with` like `DT[, v := with(rle(VALUE), max(lengths[values == 1])), by=GROUP_ID]`. I guess this (and your way as well) will throw an error if there are no 1s for a group, since `max(1L[FALSE])` is not an int, though arguably that's OP's problem.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `ave` with `rle` and get maximum occurrence of consecutive 1's for each group. (`GROUP_ID`)

```
df$Consecutive <- ave(df$VALUE, df$GROUP_ID, FUN = function(x) {
      y <- rle(x == 1)
      max(y$lengths[y$values])
})

df
#   GROUP_ID VALUE Consecutive
#1         1     0           4
#2         1     1           4
#3         1     1           4
#4         1     1           4
#5         1     1           4
#6         1     0           4
#7         2     1           3
#8         2     1           3
#9         2     0           3
#10        2     1           3
#11        2     1           3
#12        2     1           3
#13        3     1           1
#14        3     0           1
#15        3     1           1
#16        3     0           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
setDT(df1)[, CONSECUTIVE := max(table(na_if(rleid(VALUE)*VALUE, 0))), .(GROUP_ID)]
df1
#    GROUP_ID VALUE  CONSECUTIVE
# 1:        1     0            4
# 2:        1     1            4
# 3:        1     1            4
# 4:        1     1            4
# 5:        1     1            4
# 6:        1     0            4
# 7:        2     1            3
# 8:        2     1            3
# 9:        2     0            3
#10:        2     1            3
#11:        2     1            3
#12:        2     1            3
#13:        3     1            1
#14:        3     0            1
#15:        3     1            1
#16:        3     0            1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(GROUP_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), VALUE = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -16L))
```